# Desynchronized market prices when placing an order via nodejs ccxt

Tags: node.js, promise, binance, ccxt

I'm using a websocket server to receive a crypto prices.

Given I got a 1500 price, I trigger an promise function to `createMarketBuyOrder` at specific amount.

```
  buyMarketOrder: async (currency, amount) => {
    await exchange.createMarketBuyOrder(currency, amount).catch(error => {
      console.log(error.message);
    })
  },
```

When I check the order on the exchange, a market price order has been created for 1500.13, sometimes 1499.76, etc. Why is that happening ? There are no commissions/fees to be added.

Comment: It could happen anything, seriously. Market price is changing all the time, it could rise or fall when your codes are running and submitting orders.

Comment: Do you have any idea what would be the smartest solution for such situation ?

Comment: There is no smartest solution unless the specific strategy is given. If you need to trade at a certain price, why not limit order?

Comment: @halfelf that's what I was thinking about as a plan B in case high-frequency price changes won't work out. thank you